# In McKay's famous proof of Cauchy's theorem, how is the number of elements in $S$ equal to $n^{p-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

[image]

I am having much difficulty seeing how $|S|=n^{p-1}$.

Comment: There are $n$ choices for each of $a_i$ (with $i = 2, 3, \ldots, p$) and (as the book states) $a_1$ is uniquely determined by other elements. So you want to use the multiplication rule: $|S| = \prod_{i=2}^p n = n^{p-1}$.

Comment: Put another way, take ANY $p-1$ elements of $G$. We can do this in $|G|^{p-1} = n^{p-1}$ ways (if we allow duplications). Then, to choose the last element of the $p$-tuple, we are *forced* to choose $a_p = (a_1a_2\cdots a_{p-1})^{-1}$, since the $p$-fold product must equal $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said by user207868 and David Wheeler, you can think of $S$ as follows:
$$S =
\left\{ 
\big(a_1 , a_2, \dots, a_{p-1}\;, (a_1a_2\cdots a_{p-1}\,)^{-1}\, \big)  \;\;\big\vert\;\;
a_i \in G \,, \forall i \in \{1,\dots,p-1\} \right\}$$

The set $S$ is therefore in bijection with the set $G^{p-1} := G \times \cdots \times G$ (with $p-1$ factors) thanks to the bijective map $f: G^{p-1} \to S$ defined by
$$f(a_1 , a_2, \dots, a_{p-1}\,)   \;=\; 
\big(a_1 , a_2, \dots, a_{p-1}\;, (a_1a_2\cdots a_{p-1}\,)^{-1}\, \big).$$

In particular, the sets $S$ and $G^{p-1}\,$ have the same cardinality, which is $|G|^{p-1} = n^{p-1}\,.$
$\qquad\qquad \blacksquare$